# infinite series and probability

Tags: probability

I have a question related to chemistry but there is math concept behind it.
Given is a chain with 27 units. I write it as $n=27$. This chain can be broken from units 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25. I have chains with different lengths in my system starting from $n=3$ to infinity.$n=27$ is just an example of one chain with a specific length. For all chains, breakage can happen from unit 3 and on. I mean the pattern of breakage is similar for all chains with different length, different $n$ values.

There is a probability of breakage from each of these units. If $P(n)$ is a probability function  in from of polynomial like:
$$P(n)= a_3n^3 + a_2n^2 + a_1n + a_0$$
  Then $P(n=0)=a_0$ means breakage from unit 3. In a similar way, $P(n=1)=a_3 + a_2 + a_1 + a_0$ means breakage from unit 5. $P(n=12)=a_312^3 + a_212^2 + a_112  + a_0$  means breakage from unit 12
.

When breakage happens from a unit, it produces two different  smaller  chains with different lengths. If we call product of breakage as $R$ then $R_{21}$ means a chain with 21 units. Lets again consider a chain with 27 units.
The products of breakage are:

From unit 3: $R_2$ and $R_{24}$ or we can write as $R_2$ and $R_{n-3}$ .

From unit 5: $R_4$ and $R_{22}$ or we can write as $R_4$ and $R_{n-5}$.

From unit 7: $R_6$ and $R_{20}$ or we can write as $R_6$ and $R_{n-7}$.

From unit 9: $R_8$ and $R_{18}$ or we can write as $R_8$ and $R_{n-9}$.

From unit 11: $R_{10}$ and $R_{16}$ or we can write as $R_{10}$ and $R_{n-11}$.

From unit 13: $R_{12}$ and $R_{14}$ or we can write as $R_{12}$ and $R_{n-13}$.

From unit 15: $R_{14}$ and $R_{12}$ or we can write as $R_{14}$ and $R_{n-15}$.

From unit 17: $R_{16}$ and $R_{10}$ or we can write as $R_{16}$ and $R_{n-17}$.

From unit 19: $R_{18}$ and $R_8$ or we can write as $R_{18}$ and $R_{n-19}$.

From unit 21: $R_{20}$ and $R_6$ or we can write as $R_{20}$ and $R_{n-21}$.

From unit 23: $R_{22}$ and $R_4$ or we can write as $R_{22}$ and $R_{n-23}$.

From unit 25: $R_{24}$ and $R_2$ or we can write as $R_{24}$ and $R_{n-25}$.

For this specific example, I need to calculate :
$$(P(0)*({2^2 + {(n-3)^2}})) + (P(1)*({4^2 + {(n-5)^2}})) +(P(2)*({6^2 + {(n-7)^2}})) +(P(3)*({8^2 + {(n-9)^2}})) +(P(4)*({10^2 + {(n-11)^2}})) +(P(5)*({12^2 + {(n-13)^2}})) + (P(6)*({14^2 + {(n-15)^2}})) + (P(7)*({16^2 + {(n-17)^2}})) + (P(8)*({18^2 + {(n-19)^2}})) + (P(9)*({20^2 + {(n-21)^2}}))+ (P(10)*({22^2 + {(n-23)^2}})) +(P(11)*({24^2 + {(n-25)^2}})) $$.

For one chain with $n=27$, I need to know the answer of the above sums.
Similarly, for the breakage of a chain with another length , another $n$ value, a similar scenario happens.
Now, I need to develop a formula for these sums. I need a formula that works for every $n$ given that $n>3$ and goes to infinity.
The formula for the sum should be just based on $n$

Thanks